# Collapse margins for floating elements in the navigation bar

Tags: html, css

There is a navigation bar. Schematically it looks like this:

```
<- LEFT        RIGHT ->
```

CSS:

```
<div style="margin-top: 25px">
  <div style="float: left">LEFT</div>
  <div style="float: right">RIGHT</div>
</div>
```

It works fine if both navigation elements are on the same line. Now if the screen is too narrow or text is lengthy, browser rearranges it:

```
<- LEFT
     RIGHT ->
```

or

```
<- LEFT LONG TEXT LONG TEXT
LONG TEXT LONG TEXT
                   RIGHT ->
```

And both elements become too close to each other (vertically). Introducing *margin-top* solves the problem for the later case:

```
<div style="margin-top: 35px">
  <div style="float: left">LEFT</div>
  <div style="float: right; margin-top: 15px">RIGHT</div>
</div>
```

But it creates an extra margin for the former:

```
| 25px  <<  outer margin
| 15px  <<  inner margin

<- LEFT        RIGHT ->
```

**Q.** How to make it work for both cases?

*Summing up:*

- top margin (counting from the top-most navigation element) is always 25px;
- if navigation items are not on the same line, there is a 15px margin between them.

Comment: how about using flex-box ?

Comment: @wyfy It would be nice if you could share a flex-box-flavour solution for the problem.

Answer (score 1):

you could try flex-box for the div that wraps your nav:

```
<div style={display: flex, flex-flow: row wrap}>
//nav items in here
</div>
```

This specify that your nav items always lay out on a row and if the screen size is smaller it automatically wraps the items

Answer (score 0):

It always happen, you cant stop it just by setting margins. For example, I have added these extra dots to your code. Now, check your snippets.

First Snippet:

```html
<div style="margin-top: 25px;">
        <div style="float: left">LEFT.............</div>
        <div style="float: right">RIGHT.............</div>
    </div>
```

Second Snippet:

```html
    <div style="margin-top: 35px">
        <div style="float: left">LEFT.............</div>
        <div style="float: right; margin-top: 15px">RIGHT.............</div>
    </div>
```

I think the best way is to set use flex-box:

```html
<div style="margin-top: 25px; display: flex;">
        <div style="float: left">LEFT.............</div>
        <div style="float: right">RIGHT.............</div>
    </div>
```

If you want to add code specific to small screen(mobile or watch), you can use following snippt:

```css
        @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
            #div_right {
                margin-top: 15px
            }
        }
```

```html
    <div style="margin-top: 25px;">
        <div style="float: left">LEFT.............</div>
        <div id="div_right" style="float: right">RIGHT.............</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks. But (1) introducing flex cancels the right alignment in the third snippet (2) margin should be added if and only if items are placed on the consequent lines (it could either happen if the screen is small or if the text is too lengthy).

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you could achieve this result using `flexbox`, squeeze the screen to see the 15px gap between 2 rows.

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-top: 25px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: space-around;
  row-gap: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">LEFT</div>
  <div class="right">RIGHTTTTTTTTTTT</div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

[From MDN:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing)

> The top and bottom margins of blocks are sometimes combined (collapsed) into a single margin whose size is the largest of the individual margins (or just one of them, if they are equal), a behavior known as margin collapsing. Note that the margins of floating and absolutely positioned elements never collapse.

I think you should define a media query to add the top margin when needed (ex: on small screen).

Assuming you have given that right div an id "right-nav", here's the demo code:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  #right-nav {
    margin-top: 15px
  }
}
```

Comment: Not a universal solution. For long navigation texts, it could happen on the big screens.

Comment: In your business case, would it ever happen to have long dynamic navigation texts or it's just fixed? Sometimes I think you need to consider your business rather a perfect universal solution. Btw, I could think of a solution using flexbox, I'll post it later.